# Given a virtual address, output the page number and offset for the given address

Tags: c

I have this code that returns page number and offset, given a virtual address. I need help to understand how this code works.

`pageNumber = (entry & PAGE_NUMBER) >> 12;`

This line in particular confuses me. What is `PAGE NUMBER`? Why there is an and operator? Why are they shifting bits of 12 positions?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PAGE_NUMBER 0xFFFFF000
#define OFFSET 0x00000FFF

int 
main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int pageNumber, offset;
    unsigned int entry;
    entry = (unsigned int)atoi(argv[1]);

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Please enter: ./assign4_1 followed by the virtual address in decimal\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("The address %d contains:\n",entry);

    //mask the page number 
    pageNumber = (entry & PAGE_NUMBER) >> 12;
    offset = entry & OFFSET;
    printf("page number = %d\n",pageNumber);
    printf("offset = %d\n",offset);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in the days when virtual memory was not a thing, only one program could span your entire primary memory/RAM on a computer at any given time. If the computer had to run multiple programs, either it had to take the entire state of this running program, save it to secondary storage such as a hard disk and then allow another program to run or additional hardware had to be added.
This is when virtual memory came to the rescue.

Paging is a mechanism that **abstracts** away the memory management from a program's perspective; due to which it seems for the process that it is using the entire address space while there is the MMU of the operating system which divides your primary memory into fixed-size blocks called pages, creates an entire virtual address space for the program and divides them into pages as well. Only the required pages are kept in main memory and others are written to secondary storage. When a program refers to an address in memory, it actually refers to an address from this virtual address space which is translated to the actual address in memory through a page-table lookup. This is called **Virtual Address Translation**.

This not only allowed running multiple programs but also programs that did not fit into your physical address space.
The virtual address consists of:

- The Page Number: which identifies which of the pages in the virtual address space 
  the address refers to.
- The Page Offset: the lower bits of the page that tell how many locations from this page the location is. These bits do not change during translation; it stays the same. In your case the three lower digits or 12 bytes are for the page offset.

`0xFFFFF000` is a bit mask for your page number. If you logical `AND` it with any address, it will extract the page number. Similarly, `0x00000FFF` is a bit mask for your page offset.

```
`0xABCDEF12 && 0xFFFFF000 = 0xABCDE000`
`0xABCDEF12 && 0x00000FFF = 0x00000F12`
```

The page offset is ready, but the page number has to be right shifted 12 bits to correct the places. Shifting right to 12 bits in binary is equivalent to shifting a hexadecimal number 3 places to the right.

Comment: In two paragraphs you explained the concept of paging better than my textbook did in 10 pages. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

`PAGE_NUMBER` is a bit mask:

```
#define PAGE_NUMBER 0xFFFFF000
```

`(entry & PAGE_NUMBER)` uses the bit-wide AND operator to clear the low-order bits of `entry`. `>> 12` means to shift the result 12 bits to the right.

So if the value of `entry` is originally `0x12345678`, the process is:

```
entry & PAGE_NUMBER => 0x12345000
0x12345000 >> 12 => 0x12345
```

To summarize, this takes a 32-bit `entry` and returns the high-order 20 bits, which contain the page number.

Comment: "bit-wide" should be "bit-wise".

Comment: Thank you! That was very clear. 
I suppose that OFFSET is a bit mask that does the same by deleting the left-most bits to obtain the 12 bits that makes the offset, right?

Answer (score 1):

### `PAGE_NUMBER`

Reg. what `#define` means, a good method for finding that out is this: Search online for documentation on what `#define` does (for instance search for "hash define c", "hash" being a name for `#`). As a side-note, I use such methods myself for learning and investigating, and such methods help myself greatly.

Reg. the constant `PAGE_NUMBER` itself, it is used for clearing the lower 12 bits (and upper bits above 32 bits!), and a possibly better name would be `PAGE_NUMBER_CLEAR` or `PAGE_SIZE`, though I haven't investigated the code deeply enough to be certain about that.

### `&` operator and 'and':

Reg. figuring out what it means, you can with advantage search for operators in C, and note what they are called. For C as well as C++, I can strongly recommend the website https://en.cppreference.com/w/ , it is very good in my experience. Look for instance at https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence .

### "Why are they shifting bits of 12 positions?":

Shifting bits that way is a common alternative to dividing by `2^n`, where `n` here would be `12`. It basically removes the last part that has been cleared by the bitwise-and, as described in the other answers.

Comment: This should be comments. If you're going to answer, provide the answers, don't just tell him what to google.

Comment: cppreference.com has been a very valuable resource in my experience, and should help guide him on how to solve his problem. And likewise, teaching him what to search for (for instance "hash" for the symbol `#`) might well be very helpful to him. And those are also the questions he asks.

Comment: If he understood the textbooks he wouldn't be asking here.

Comment: But what if he doesn't have a textbook that covers it? Or doesn't know where or what to search for?

Comment: I know what those operands do and what #define does, I'm overall confused about why those operations are done and why PAGE_NUMBER is a hex number.

Comment: But did you know that `&` is the bitwise-and operator, not just the regular `&&` boolean 'and' operator? See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence .

Comment: Yes, I looked that up, but still couldn't figure out why they were doing bitwise-and operator with an int and a hex number. Thanks for the website tho!

Comment: You're welcome :). cppreference.com is really, really nice, at least in my experience. I might also have misunderstood what you were asking for and what you had tried and investigated.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26330151)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε It gives guidance towards how to figure out two of the questions, and the question asker himself gave a 'thanks' for the reference to the website in the comments. If deleted, the references and links (including in the comments) would disappear.

Comment: @ModusTollens That is not quite accurate, for it gives instructions on how to search as well as resources that are useful in general, not simply links or references. For instance, it instructs on how to search "#define" , namely with a "hash define", which may not be obvious to new programmers. The instructions are general and can be used for the programmer in the future. I use such methods myself when solving problems.

Comment: @ModusTollens I am not convinced that you are interpreting the rules of Stack Overflow correctly. But you are right that I forgot to answer the third question, and I have just added an answer reg. that.

Comment: @ModusTollens Yeah, but everyone can make mistakes after all :).

Comment: @ModusTollens And again, I consider it much more valuable to teach others how to fish than simply giving them a fish. Isn't that a much, much better answer and help? It might also make sense to amend the rules if there is room for improvement, though that should be looked at through meta-exchange as far as I know.

Comment: @ModusTollens The last part of the edited answer is definitely not a comment, that is a very direct and clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

`PAGE_NUMBER` is 0xFFFFF000.  That's just a fancy way of writing 11111111111111111111000000000000 in binary.

`entry & PAGE_NUMBER` uses the `&` operator, which is "bitwise and".  Since any bit (x) when and-ed to 0 (x & 0) can only be 0, the operation entry & PAGE_NUMBER, clears the lower 12 bits.

Now that the desired bits are collected, we have one last step.  The bits we want are in the wrong (base 2) places.  We need to move them, such that the lowest bit is in the (base 2) one's place.  We could divide, but there is a better operation, a "shift right" or `>>` operator.  `(entry & PAGE_NUMBER) >> 12` moves the value 12 bits to the right.

With these three operations, you have the desired bits, aligned to be a number where the smallest non-zero value is 1.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I recommend you to read something about OS and virtual memory, I recommend this:

https://www.bottomupcs.com/virtual_addresses.xhtml

and some posts for c programming:

https://medium.com/@SravanthiSinha/all-about-the-virtual-memory-1c8a3cf306b7

You can find plenty of them googling.

Returning to your code, I recommend to experiment with c code using [cling](https://root.cern.ch/cling) and a good ide setup for example I use the combination Emacs + eglot.

Now we are ready to experiment with your code.

If we use cling:

```
[cling]$ #include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

[cling]$ #define PAGE_NUMBER 0xFFFFF000
[cling]$ PAGE_NUMBER
(unsigned int) 4294963200

[cling]$ #define OFFSET 0x00000FFF
[cling]$ OFFSET
(int) 4095
```

The program uses 1 input argv[1](https://www.bottomupcs.com/virtual_addresses.xhtml) (+ program name argv[0]), anssing the first to entry:

let's supose that we compile clang -Wall name.c -o name and  call like ./name 19986

```
[cling]$  entry = (unsigned int)atoi("19986");
[cling]$ entry
(unsigned int) 19986
```

then check the correctness of the input.

then it do some [bitwise operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) to the integers to maks the page number and and shift, the program do it because it is faster than divide mask numbers, bits of integers

```
[cling]$ (entry & PAGE_NUMBER) >> 12
(unsigned int) 4
[cling]$ entry & OFFSET
(unsigned int) 3602
```

and print the numbers in the screen:

if I name the code with virtual_adress.c and compile clang -Wall virtual_address.c -o virtual_adress
 and execute

```
❯ ./virtual_adress 19986
The address 19986 contains:
page number = 4
offset = 3602
```

That is the same that we execute step by step in cling. I hope that did helped to find the solution to yopur original assiggment